# How can I add a clone of a node from one XML document into a different one?

Tags: java, dom

I have the following code:

```
private static Node GetText(String name)
{
    Node ret = textRoots.get(name);
    if (ret!=null)
    {
        ret=ret.cloneNode(true);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And in a different method, I have the following lines:

```
Node textNode = GetText(name);
node.replaceChild(textNode, inner);
```

I would like this to work even if Node and the original document, which text comes from, happen to be different documents; how can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Document.importNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on what you want to do!

If you just want to have that node in the other document you can use the `importNode(...)` method:

```
// someNode was created by another document
Node someNodeNew = doc2.importNode(someNode, true);
```

Now you can just add `someNodeNew` somewhere in `doc2`.

Doing this will create a **copy** of the old node!

---

If you want to move the node (including all subchilds) to another document you have 2 possibilities:

1. **Using the documents `adoptNode(...)` method:**

If it works, it will change the owner document of the node and will remove it from the old document. There's only one **problem** using this method:

*The Javadoc states:*

> Attempts to adopt a node from another document to this document. If supported, it changes the owner document [...]

So this method does not have to be supported and might fail!

2. **The second (and in my opinion better) option:**

Import the Node and then remove it out of the old tree:

```
// someNode was created by another document
Node someNodeNew = doc2.importNode(someNode, true);
if (someNode.getParentNode() != null)
    someNode.getParentNode().removeChild(someNode);
someNode = someNodeNew ;
```

Comment: Since the code I displayed above indicates that I want a copy (I used Node.clone(true) in the method shown above), I clearly want the first option you stated.

Comment: Glad i could help ;) Just make sure to set the second parameter from `importNode(Node, boolean)` to true in order to receive a "deep-copy" (if you need that)